# staircase function tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to remove the vertical straight lines (in the staircase function), keep only the dashed ones and make the horizontal lines bold:

[image]

Also, I don't know why the dashed lines exceed the y-axis value I've given and why they are displaced.

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\begin{axis}[
axis x line=bottom,
axis y line=left,
xlabel={A},
ylabel=B},xmax=8,ymax=8,
xtick={2,6},xticklabels={$bs_1$,$bs_k$},
ytick={2,3,6},yticklabels={$b_1$,$b_2$,$b_k$}
]
\addplot [mark=none,draw=blue]
coordinates {(1,1)(1,2)(2,2)(2,3)(3,3)(3,4)(4,4)(4,5)(5,5)(5,6)(6,6)(6,7)(7,7)};
\end{axis}
\draw [dashed,draw=blue] (1,1) -- (1,0);
\draw [dashed,draw=blue] (2,2) -- (2,0);
\draw [dashed,draw=blue] (3,3) -- (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A B C}
\end{figure}
```

**EDIT:**

How can I add `\cdots` between the xticklabels ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the `\draw` commands in the `axis`, and there is a plot handler that suppress the vertical "jumps", so it suffices to say

```
\addplot [jump mark left,mark=none,draw=blue,domain=1:7,samples=7,thick]{x+1};
```

The `\cdots` can be added as an `extra x tick`, which you do not draw.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\begin{axis}[ymin=1,
axis x line=bottom,
axis y line=left,
xlabel={A},
ylabel=B,xmax=8,ymax=8,
xtick={2,6},xticklabels={$bs_1$,$bs_k$},
ytick={2,3,6},yticklabels={$b_1$,$b_2$,$b_k$},
extra x ticks={4},extra x tick label={$\cdots$},
extra x tick style={tick style={draw=none}}
]
% \addplot [mark=none,draw=red]
% coordinates {(1,1)(1,2)(2,2)(2,3)(3,3)(3,4)(4,4)(4,5)(5,5)(5,6)(6,6)(6,7)(7,7)};
\addplot [jump mark left,mark=none,draw=blue,domain=1:7,samples=7,thick]
{x+1};
\draw [dashed,draw=blue] (1,1) -- (1,0);
\draw [dashed,draw=blue] (2,2) -- (2,0);
\draw [dashed,draw=blue] (3,3) -- (3,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A B C}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or `ultra thick`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\begin{axis}[ymin=1,
axis x line=bottom,
axis y line=left,
xlabel={A},
ylabel=B,xmax=8,ymax=8,
xtick={2,6},xticklabels={$bs_1$,$bs_k$},
ytick={2,3,6},yticklabels={$b_1$,$b_2$,$b_k$},
extra x ticks={4},extra x tick label={$\cdots$},
extra x tick style={tick style={draw=none}}
]
% \addplot [mark=none,draw=red]
% coordinates {(1,1)(1,2)(2,2)(2,3)(3,3)(3,4)(4,4)(4,5)(5,5)(5,6)(6,6)(6,7)(7,7)};
\addplot [jump mark left,mark=none,draw=blue,domain=1:7,samples=7,ultra thick]
{x+1};
\draw [dashed,draw=blue] (1,1) -- (1,0);
\draw [dashed,draw=blue] (2,2) -- (2,0);
\draw [dashed,draw=blue] (3,3) -- (3,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A B C}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's working! Do you have any idea how can I make those horizontal lines bold and how I can I add the \cdots to the xticklabels ?

Comment: @A.Afaf These lines are already `thick`. Do you want them to become even thicker? And I added the `\cdots` just now.

Comment: if it's possible, if not it's not a big deal the most important is `\cdots`

Comment: @A.Afaf It is not problem to increase the line width, I added another example with `ultra thick`. The `\cdots` were already in.

Comment: It's working ! thank you !

Comment: can I skip some of the horizontal lines? I mean not to draw them.

Comment: @A.Afaf Of course. You can just use `\addplot [jump mark left,mark=none,draw=blue,domain=1:3,samples=3,ultra thick]
{x+1};
\addplot [jump mark left,mark=none,draw=blue,domain=5:7,samples=3,ultra thick]
{x+1};`, i.e. two plots. Alternatively you could add a filter.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you draw the picture as simple as it is?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw 
(1,0)--+(-90:.1) node[below]{$bs_1$}
(3,0) +(-90:.1)  node[below]{$\cdots$}
(5,0)--+(-90:.1) node[below]{$bs_k$}
(0,1)--+(180:.1) node[left]{$b_1$}
(0,2)--+(180:.1) node[left]{$b_2$}
(0,5)--+(180:.1) node[left]{$b_k$};
\draw[magenta,dashed] (1,0)--+(90:1) (2,0)--+(90:2);
\foreach \j in {1,...,6}
\draw[magenta,line width=2pt] (\j-1,\j)--+(0:1);
\draw[stealth-stealth] (0,7)|-(7,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh ! I didn't know abt this. Could you please explain it a little bit? I use latex to write I've never used it to draw functions, I am new to it.

Comment: @A.Âf just study this manual https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf